# When does the Webpack bundle occur?

Tags: javascript, webpack, cors, localhost, es6-modules

I am learning [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) modules at this current time. It took me so long to finally understand and be proficient in closures, [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)s and scope using one script that I was almost upset to find ES6 modules bring about a different, more manageable way to organise modular code into various different scripts and then for a bundler like [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack) to bundle it all back into one (or only a few) scripts.

1. I get the normal cross origin error when I put script type = ‘module’ and try to run modules on my local file system which is different to when I run a normal script just simply specifying a src!

   Wherever I look the solution is to use a local host to get round this which I have done! But at what point does Webpack work its bundling? Is it when I run it in the command line or when it’s loaded into the browser?
2. If installing Webpack via [npm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_(software)) in my project and setting up the configuration, does this mean I wouldn’t have to use a local host because my distribution code during the runtime is now in one script file, so it doesn’t have to import scripts not on the same URL?

   I know it’s only on my local file system, but I cannot request scripts in the same folder when using ES6 modules due to the cross origin policy as I could if just specifying a script src without using modules.

Answer (score 0):

Each time I run Webpack from the command line, it bundles together the latest code taken from the entry point (specified during my configuration).

This means I can use the ES6 module syntax on my entry file without having to use a live server as I never intend to load this JavaScript entry file into the browser. It’s simply to be the controller of all other script exports by importing what I need from them.

Then this script will be the target of Webpacks bundling (the entry point) meaning the only script that is loaded into the browser is the bundled script, which has no other imports. This avoids the need to run a live server when testing ES6 modules!!

If not using Webpack, I would have to run a server because my main script would be importing other scripts and unless they have the same URL (they don’t even have one yet in my file system) then I will get a cross origin error. As soon as I run my local server 127.0.0.1 then it would work. I prefer testing with Webpack.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).